# Error Using MySQL and PHP to generate HTML webpages

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

For a class project I decided to create something sort've akin to a simplified Wordpress that generates HTML layouts based on user choices.

Now everything almost works perfectly except attributes in html get messed up with a lot of "\"'s being inserted. (I've noticed it's near quotation marks so my theory is that when MYSQLi is writing running the query, its adding the slashes to protect the query)

anyways here is the code for the relevant part

```
if ($stmt = $db_link->prepare("INSERT INTO pages (pageid, pagetitle, styleid,pagetypeid, importheader, importfooter, javascript, multiplepages, bodyhtml, additionalnotes)

VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

// Bind the variables to the parameter as strings. 
$stmt->bind_param("isiissssss",$pageid,$pagetitle,$stylesheet,$pagetype,$header,$footer,$javascript,$multiplepages,$html,$notes);
// Execute the query
$stmt->execute();
// Close the prepared statement.
$stmt->close();
}
```

Here is what the HTML should look like:

```
<div class='main'><div class='nav'><br><a href='#' class='myButton'>hey</a><br><a href='#' class='myButton'>hey</a><br><a href='#' class='myButton'>hey</a><br><a href='#' class='myButton'>hey</a></div><div class='frame'> 

<p id='paragraph'>hopefully the last test</p></div></div></div>
</div>
```

And here is what it does look like:

```
<div class=\'main\'><div class=\'nav\'><br><a href=\'#\' class=\'myButton\'>hey</a><br><a href=\'#\' class=\'myButton\'>hey</a><br><a href=\'#\' class=\'myButton\'>hey</a><br><a href=\'#\' class=\'myButton\'>hey</a></div><div class=\'frame\'> \r\n\r\n<p id=\'paragraph\'>hopefully the last test</p></div></div></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>
```

I know that \n reffers to the return character so I'm guessing similarly \' reffers to ' character. The question is how do I stop this from happening? Also for the record, I know the problem is definitely with the entering the query through this program as the HTML I manually inserted with phpMyAdmin works perfectly.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out. Thank you so much!

EDIT: I figured it out! Sort've. At any rate how to fix it. I was using the

> mysqli_real_escape_string();

function before I tried to remove the "\n"'s and "\r"'s using

> str_replace();

and

> stripslashes();

So now its obvious why that wasn't working. It still doesn't solve the problem of why the slashes were generated in the first place but at least now I have a solution that will make the code work. I hope if anyone else has this issue that they see this!

Comment: where is the code that turns your SQL data back into HTML? Because that's where this is going wrong, but is also not in your post.

Comment: Print $html before you run the request. And tell us it's value

Comment: Have you tried using `stripslashes()`?

Comment: When I print $html it is the same as the second html with the "\"'s inserted into it. I'm positive whatever's happening, its on this end of the PHP

Comment: stripslashes() almost works but it still leaves the r's and n's from the "\r"'s and "\n"'s. So if someone could help me get at the more core problem here, that would be ideal

Comment: *but what that implies to me is that the slashes are being added when I post from the form. so I don't know what other information I should give everyone

Comment: I'm using a form with POST to fetch all the variables if that makes a difference...

Comment: Okay, so use `stripslashes()` and `nl2br()` in the meantime then. That should remove all of that. Not sure why its adding all of that. How are you storing your HTML data in the DB? Whats the field type?

Comment: I'm using a VARCHAR with a very long length. Is that an issue?

Comment: TEXT would be more appropriate for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Did some digging around and I found this to be a common solution to the HTML storage issue. Try this out: [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) This library will enable you to safely store HTML along with other features.

You should also use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) This will convert any characters that are "bad" and convert them into the HTML equivalent. IE: ' is converted to "&#039" and store that in the database. Then you can use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` to revert it back.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have, for some reasons, magic quotes activated. It would explain your issue...

What does this return : get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? If true, you have the solution. If false, I'm wrong. That feature no more exists since PHP5.4.

Can you try disabling it in your php.ini configuration ?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't matter because its on my school's server so I couldn't edit it if I wanted

Comment: I'm trying to use str_replace("\n"," ",$html); now but it doesn't appear to work

Comment: but still, what's the return of this function ? true or false ?